# JSf request scope in simple blog

Tags: java, jsf-2, scope

I am trying to create simple blog with jsf 2.0. It contains 2 classes:

BlogManager (in session scope)
Blog(in request scope)

```
@Named("blogManager")
@SessionScoped
public class BlogManager {
    private List<Blog> blogs;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{blog}")
    Blog blog;

    public BlogManager() {
        blogs = new ArrayList<Blog>();
    }

    public List<Blog> getBlogs() {
        return blogs;
    }

    public void setBlogs(List<Blog> blogs) {
        this.blogs = blogs;
    }

    public Blog getBlog() {
        return blog;
    }

    public void setBlog(Blog blog) {
        this.blog = blog;
    }

    public void addBlog() {
        blogs.add(blog);
    }

    public void removeBlog(Blog blog) {
        blogs.add(blog);
    }
}
```

the blog class:

```
@Named("blog")
@RequestScoped
public class Blog {

    private Integer id;

    private String title;
    private String text;
    private Date date;

    public Blog() {
        id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private Integer readed;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Integer getReaded() {
        return readed;
    }

    public void setReaded(Integer readed) {
        this.readed = readed;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

then inside my xhtml form i am writing this thing:

```
<h:form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Blog</legend>
                <p>
                    Title:
                    <h:inputText value="#{blog.title}" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    Text:
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{blog.text}" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <h:commandButton action="#{blogManager.addBlog}" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </h:form>
```

when i click submit it says blog target unreachable. It is request scope. I was thinking once jsf could not find the blog object then it creates and assigns user input to blog object. then i can see it in blogManager. But it does not work. what scope should i use for Blog class? And can i inject request scope in blogManager?

thanks

Comment: Just curious, your `blog` bean does not seem to have any behavior, so what is the need of defining it as a `RequestScoped` bean? Why not keep it a simple pojo?

Comment: if I do it simple pojo then i can not use it in xhml page for user input: for example for this: <h:inputText value="#{blog.title}" />

Comment: What happens, if you use `@ManagedBean("YourBean")` annotation instead of using `@Named("YourBean")`? Give it a try.

Comment: @elbek: Of course you can. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, your `Blog` class should only be a POJO. And it should be a member of `BlogManager`. So the only bean you need will be 
BlogManager :

```
@Named("blogManager")
@SessionScoped
public class BlogManager {
    private List<Blog> blogs;

    private Blog blog;

    public BlogManager() {
        blogs = new ArrayList<Blog>();
            blog = new Blog();
    }

    // getter setters for blog and blogs

    public void addBlog() {
        blogs.add(blog);
    }

    public void removeBlog(Blog blog) {
        blogs.add(blog);
    }
}
```

the blog class:

```
public class Blog {

    private Integer id;

    private String title;
    private String text;
    private Date date;
    private Integer readed;

    public Blog() {
        id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    // getters-setters

}
```

And your xhtml :

```
<h:form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Blog</legend>
                <p>
                    Title:
                    <h:inputText value="#{blogManager.blog.title}" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    Text:
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{blogManager.blog.text}" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <h:commandButton action="#{blogManager.addBlog}" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: this is how i did for second time, But the problem is all time jsf class constructor of BlogManager for each request? It is supposed to be in session and should be created once per session. Am i wrong?

Comment: That is weird indeed! You're right, it should not be called more than once. Something is wrong somewhere else..

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing JSF and CDI annotations. You have managed your beans by CDI's `@Named`, but yet you're trying to use JSF specific `@ManagedProperty` annotation to inject one CDI managed bean in another CDI managed bean. This is not going to work. You need to use CDI's own `@Inject` annotation instead. The `@ManagedProperty` works only with JSF `@ManagedBean` classes.

Fix it accordingly:

```
@Inject
private Blog blog;
```

Further you also need to make absolutely sure that when you manage beans by CDI's `@Named`, that all the scope annotations like `@SessionScoped` are coming from the `javax.enterprise.context` package and not from the `javax.faces.bean` package.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this design is flawy. The `Blog` class should not be a managed bean, but an `@Entity` and be just a normal property of the `BlogManager` class.

Comment: oops.. I clearly ignored the fact that its CDI annotations. yours should be marked as the answer rather than mine!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject a lower scoped object to a higher scoped object. Thus you cannot inject request scoped object `blog` to your session scoped `blogManager`. If you create it as a simple pojo, you can access it always like `<h:inputText value="#{blogManager.blog.title}" />`

Comment: +1 for `You cannot inject a lower scoped object to a higher scoped object`

Comment: Wrong, this is only true for JSF managed beans, not for CDI managed beans.